# how to pass table row selected using checkbox in html n pass the data to views.py django

Tags: javascript, python, django

m new to python-django need help...
i want to pass the selected table row from template to views.py with checkbox checked using post method..and can select multiple rows...
n after submitting the row with POST method to views.py the selected row should get disappear from template

```
template:a.html 
<tr > {% if getlog %}
<form action="{% url list %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<td><input type="checkbox" id="check_all" checked="checked"/></td>          
<thead><th COLSPAN="2">App Name</th>
    <th COLSPAN="2">File Name</th>
    <th COLSPAN="2">Function Name</th>
    <th COLSPAN="2">Path Name</th>
    <th COLSPAN="2">Line No</th>
    <th COLSPAN="2">Level Name</th>
    <th COLSPAN="2">Message</th>
    <th COLSPAN="2">Thread Name</th>
</tr>                                                                
</thead>
{% for log in loglist %}
<tr id="tr1">
<td><input type="checkbox" class="check_field" checked="checked" name="list1"/> </td>
   <td colspan="2" > {{ log.app.appname }} </td>
   <td colspan="2"> {{ log.filename }}</td>
   <td colspan="2" >{{ log.funcname }}</td>
   <td colspan="2" >{{ log.pathname }}</td>
   <td colspan="2" >{{ log.lineno }}</td>
   <td colspan="2" >{{ log.typeid.levelname }}</td>
   <td colspan="2" >{{ log.typeid.message }}</td>
   <td colspan="2">{{ log.threadName }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}      
</tbody>
</table>
```

how to do that???where m going wrong?
thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going wrong by using a non-Django way of handling data submission.

Django's power lies in a very robust forms system which can generate the forms for you as well as handling common tasks like saving records to the database, form validation, etc.

I know it's a pain but it **really is worth it** to take some time to run through the Django book and do some sample exercies so you can get familiar with Django basics. With that in hand you can think about what steps you'd take to move forward on the things you actually want to do.

Yours is a special case so a straightforward formset or ModelForm won't really do the trick, here's an impementation that I'd recommend.

**models.py**

```
class Log(models.Model):
    # whatever fields you want
    date_hidden = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class LogDisplayForm(forms.Form):
    logs_to_hide = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=Log.objects.exclude(date_hidden__isnull=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.cleaned_data.get('logs_to_hide'):
            Log.object.filter(pk__in=self.cleaned_data['logs_to_hide']).update(date_hidden=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Then in your template form, just rename list1 to logs_to_hide and make sure the value of the field is the primary key of the log record. This assumes that you read up on how Django actually works and know how you'd handle form validation and form saving in the view.

Note that the code I have given you is incomplete and won't work without considerable additional work on your part. **Which is the *point*.**

Comment: okay i will read the doc.. but is there any other way to pass <tr> data with form?? i read in one of the answers k it by default http object sends the list of checked checkboxes n in views.py i can get it using list= request.POST.getlist('checkbox_name')

Comment: Sorry, this question is basically unanswerable because you don't have enough of an understanding of how this all works. I really think going through the docs and learning the basics of how forms work is necessary. Fundamentally, the reason what you're doing isn't working is because you need to be sending actual values to your view function, which you're not doing. If you follow my instructions along with reading up the docs it will work. The template you have set up will never work as is.

Comment: thanks... m reading the doc..but not getting in which direction i should work..i should go for django-forms k javascript.. coz i need to get that selected checkbox table row..so how can i bind that checkbox with table row?? and how can i get actual data.. ??confused...